# Why does malloc produce seg fault when accessing a member reference from C++ struct?

Tags: c++

Consider the following code example:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    int x = 2;  
    int &rx = x;
};

int main()
{
    Foo *f1 = new Foo[4];
    std::cout<< f1[0].rx <<std::endl; //ok

    Foo *f2 = (Foo*) malloc (4 * sizeof(Foo));
    std::cout<< f2[0].rx <<std::endl; //memory leak
    
    free(f2);
    delete [] f1;
}
```

When `new` is used to allocate memory, the member reference `rx` is accessed normally and the correct value is printed. However, when `malloc` is used, accessing the member reference produces a segmentation fault. Can you please explain why?

I suspect a collision of C vs C++ implementation, but I'm not sure.

I ran the code with an address sanitizer which produced the following output:

```
ASAN:SIGSEGV
=================================================================
==32515==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: SEGV on unknown address 0x000000000000 (pc 0x00000048cb69 sp 0x7ffea3d6bf40 bp 0x7ffea3d6bf70 T0)
    #0 0x48cb68 in main /home/.../Desktop/test.cpp:15
    #1 0x7f9861fb1544 in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x22544)
    #2 0x405578 (/home/.../Desktop/a.out+0x405578)

AddressSanitizer can not provide additional info.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: SEGV /home/.../Desktop/test.cpp:15 main
==32515==ABORTING
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add the subscript ops. But unfortunately, that's not what's causing the mem leak.

Comment: `malloc` doesn't start the lifetime of an object, which includes not running any constructor, which includes not running default member initializers. At no point does `f2` ever point to a `Foo` object. Note that the error shown is a segmentation fault which crashes the program. This is very different from a memory leak which is just an object which is never destroyed or released when it's no longer needed or reachable, wasting resources but should not cause the program to crash.

Comment: @user7860670 nope this is not that: https://godbolt.org/z/z7rhsqfsr problem is undefined behavior in line 14-15

Comment: `Foo *f2 = (Foo*) malloc (4 * sizeof(Foo));`.  No object is created with this.  The traits of the `Foo` class is not standard layout.  [See this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/463956ddd243ba99).

Comment: `int &rx = x;` does this happen when you use `malloc()` ? I don't think rx is initialized

Comment: @MarekR - nice reference to sanitizer in godbolt. didn't know you could get it from there too.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie OF COURSE!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! AARRRGGG!!!!!!!!

Comment: why do you think this would be a leak?

Comment: C knows nothing about references, thus `malloc` will also know nothing about references.  If you want to guarantee your type can be used with C-style functions to create, copy (i.e. `memcpy`), etc., you should use the functions in [<type_traits>](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/type_traits) to guarantee what you're doing will actually work correctly.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie - I assumed it would have been a collision with the languages, but I was in a C++ mindset and forgot that malloc does not initialize anything. Just allocates memory. Thanks!

Comment: If the alignment of your buffer is correct, you should still be able to use placement-new on it.

Comment: Placement new silences address sanitizer tool: https://godbolt.org/z/vz5b5n3YW but this code is still bad (possible alignment issue).

Comment: The thing to take away here, either do C, or do C++. Do not mix the two. Don't use C constructs in C++ code if you can *possibly* avoid them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason of the SEGV is because the new operator calls the class default constructor, it is where the initialization of the non-static data members is done, in this case setting x to 2 and rx to x.

When you allocate the memory with malloc the default constructor is not called. So the SEGV rises because rx is never set to point to x, it is an undefined behavior.

You have to call the default constructor explicitly, with "new(f2) Foo", it is called [**placement new operator**](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/placement-new-operator-cpp/).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <malloc.h>

struct Foo
{
    int x = 2;  
    int &rx = x;
};

int main()
{
    Foo *f1 = new Foo[4];
    std::cout<< f1[0].rx <<std::endl; //ok

    Foo *f2 = (Foo*) malloc (4 * sizeof(Foo));
    new(f2) Foo;
    std::cout<< f2[0].rx <<std::endl; //memory leak
    
    free(f2);
    delete f1;
}
```

Here the **placement new operator** doesn't allocate memory it only calls the default constructor for the memory object allocated with malloc.

Now the result is what you expect.

```
2
2
```